# Create new array from existing array JavaScript by repeating the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my project I have a requirement to create a new array form existing array. For example if the original array is like

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I need to create the new array of length 7 means it should be like below

```
var newArr = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2];
```

The new array length is dynamic, if the length is going to 9 means it should be like

```
var newArr = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4];
```

and if it going to be 15 means it should be like below

```
var newArr = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
```

The new array should be created by repeating the original array based on the dynamic length.

Comment: What did you try, any code , attempts you made please add it to your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option, using `Array.from` and modulo:

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
const makeNewArr = length => Array.from(
  { length },
  (_, i) => arr1[i % arr1.length]
);

console.log(makeNewArr(7));
```

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance ,if the array is alphabets instead of numbers like var arr1 = [a,b,c,d,e]; means getting some error.could you please give some input on this

Comment: What the array contains should have no effect - the solution should work regardless. If you want the original array to be an array of characters, your syntax is incorrect - strings must be enclosed in `'` (or `"`) delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a simple for loop.

```js
function generateArray(length) {
  var arr = [];
  var max = 5;
  var value = 1;
  
  for (var i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    if (value > max) {
      value = value % max;
    }
    arr.push(value);
    value++;
  }

   return arr;
}


// Using toString() to display output in one line.
console.log(generateArray(7).toString());
console.log(generateArray(9).toString());
console.log(generateArray(15).toString());
```